# Getting folders size in windows directly

Tags: windows

If I select 1 or more files in windows, I can directly get their size as you can see in snapshot.
.
.
.

[image: as you can see]

But if I select folders I don't get their size directly. I have to select folders , open their properties and then get their size.
Is there any direct way to get their size?

Comment: Try the alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/windows-explorer/

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it isn't currently possible to view directory sizes in Windows Explorer (without going into properties).

You ***can***, however, use a third party tool (such as [TreeSize Free](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/)) to review directory sizes.

Comment: Even if you view a directory it's not instant. Windows still needs to read the index for the directory. Viewing the size of items in a directory requires you to read the index of said directory. Those recursive lookups take time which is why they are not the "default".

Comment: It partially solved my problem . Thanks a lot.